# Properties of an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S$ be a ring with $1$ such that $x \in S$ there is a $y \in S$ such that $xys = x$.

Let $I$ non-zero left ideal of $S$. Please help me to show that $I^2 $ is not equal to ${0\right\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ be a non-zero element of $I$. Take $b\in R$ such that $aba=a$. Since $I$ is a left-ideal, $ba\in I$, so $a=a(ba)\in I^2$ and hence $I^2$ contains a non-zero element.

Comment: where you use the fact that the ideal is minimal?

Comment: I don't use that fact.

Comment: can us prove that $I$ is a principle ideal?

Comment: Apart from this not being part of the question asked, minimal ideals being principal is a trivial statement.

Comment: have you please a reference whare i can find a proof of this statement? thanks in advance

Comment: $0\neq x\in I \quad\Rightarrow\quad \{0\}\subsetneq (x) \subseteq I \quad\Rightarrow\quad I=(x)$.

Comment: and in this case do we have $I^2=I$?

Comment: Please ask a question containing all that you are asking for. This comment section is not a chat.

Comment: i am sorry and thanks for your help